# xcodebuild couldn't read dependency graph from ... .... : Permission denied

Tags: file-permissions, xcodebuild

Today I experienced the following error from xcodebuild:

> xcodebuild couldn't read dependency graph from ... .... : Permission denied

And further down:

> Details:  unable to write dependency graph: You don’t have permission to save the file “my-app.build” in the folder “my-target-iphoneos”.

I am documenting this since the cause is really obscure, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Xcode *Organizer* window open, while attempting to build the app from the command line, it locks the build directory, resulting in the file permissions error.

If you close the *Organizer* window you will be able to build from the command line again.